# finding an orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

I have a vector $[-1/3, 1/3, 4/3]$ and another vector $[1, 1, 0]$ and I need to find an another orthogonal vector that are orthogonal to both vectors but could not find a method. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Outer product of the two given vectors?

Comment: [Cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)?

Comment: @thanasissdr could you give a detailed answer please so i could rate you up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that an orthogonal vector has zero dot product with the given vectors.  Let our vector be $[x,y,z]$.
\begin{align*}
    [x,y,z] &\cdot [-1/3, 1/3, 4/3] &&\hspace{-0.41in}= -x/3 + y/3 + 4z/3 &&\hspace{-0.41in}= 0  \\
    [x,y,z] &\cdot [1, 1, 0] &&\hspace{-0.41in}= x + y + 0 &&\hspace{-0.41in}= 0  \text{.}
\end{align*}
From the second, $y = -x$.  Plugging into the first, $-2x/3 + 4z/3 = 0$.  This gives a line full of solutions (which is to be expected).  Pick any of them, say $[2,0,1]$.

Comment: You were faster!

Comment: @egreg : I have very quick fingers (and a *lot* of LaTeX practice).

Comment: More LaTeX practice than me? Go figure! `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach.

Let $u = [-1/3,1/3,4/3]$  and $ v = [1,1,0]$. According to [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) we have that the cross product $u\times v$ of $u,v$ will be:
$$u \times v =\begin{vmatrix}
 \vec i & \vec j & \vec k \\
-\frac 13& \frac 13 &\frac 43\\
1 & 1 & 0
 \end{vmatrix}=-\frac 43 \, \vec i +  \frac 43 \,\vec j -\frac23 \, \vec k. $$

Thus, we can consider the third vector $[-4/3, 4/3, -2/3]$. We can verify that it is orthogonal to the other $2$ vectors taking their inner products.

Comment: The big downside of this method is that it strongly depends on the space being $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the standard inner product.

Comment: @egreg Yes, of course, the other method is  more elegant, but at least it is an option (when nothing else comes to mind).

Answer (score 0):

For two vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ one can use the cross product to find a vector orthogonal to the plane created by the original two vectors. Consider $v,w\in\Bbb R^3$ where $v=[v_1,v_2,v_3]$ and $w=[w_1,w_2,w_3]$ for $v_1,v_2,v_3,w_1,w_2,w_3\in\Bbb R$. The cross product of $v$ and $w$ is given by:
$$v\times w=[v_2w_3-v_3w_2,v_3w_1-v_1w_3,v_1w_2-v_2w_1]$$
and the vector $v\times w\in\Bbb R^3$ is orthogonal to both $v$ and $w$.

Letting $v=\left[\frac{-1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{4}{3}\right]$ and $w=\left[1,1,0\right]$, we have:
$$v\times w=\left[\frac{1}{3}\cdot0-\frac{4}{3}\cdot1,\frac{4}{3}\cdot1-\frac{-1}{3}\cdot0,\frac{-1}{3}\cdot1-\frac{1}{3}\cdot1\right]=\left[\frac{-4}{3},\frac{4}{3},\frac{-2}{3}\right]$$
So choose your orthogonal vector to be $\left[\frac{-4}{3},\frac{4}{3},\frac{-2}{3}\right]$.